# ycsb load run elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, benchmarking

I'm trying to run the benchmark software yscb on ElasticSearch

The problem I'm having is that after the load, the data seems to get removed during cleanup.

I'm struggling to understand what is supposed to happen?

If I comment out the cleanup, it still fails because it cannot find the index during the "run" phase.

Can someone please explain what is supposed to happen in YSCB?

I mean I think it would have
1. load phase: load say 1,000,000 records
2. run phase: query the records loaded during the "load phase"

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have discovered by running Couchbase in YCSB that the data shouldn't be removed.

Looking at cleanup() for ElasticSearchClient I see no reason why the files would be deleted (?)

```
@Override
public void cleanup() throws DBException {
    if (!node.isClosed()) {
        client.close();
        node.stop();
        node.close();
    }
}
```

The init is as follows: any reason this would not persist on the filesystem?

```
public void init() throws DBException {
    // initialize OrientDB driver
    Properties props = getProperties();
    this.indexKey = props.getProperty("es.index.key", DEFAULT_INDEX_KEY);
    String clusterName = props.getProperty("cluster.name", DEFAULT_CLUSTER_NAME);
    Boolean newdb = Boolean.parseBoolean(props.getProperty("elasticsearch.newdb", "false"));
    Builder settings = settingsBuilder()
            .put("node.local", "true")
            .put("path.data", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/esdata")
            .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", "false")
            .put("index.mapping._id.indexed", "true")
            .put("index.gateway.type", "none")
            .put("gateway.type", "none")
            .put("index.number_of_shards", "1")
            .put("index.number_of_replicas", "0");


    //if properties file contains elasticsearch user defined properties
    //add it to the settings file (will overwrite the defaults).
    settings.put(props);
    System.out.println("ElasticSearch starting node = " + settings.get("cluster.name"));
    System.out.println("ElasticSearch node data path = " + settings.get("path.data"));

    node = nodeBuilder().clusterName(clusterName).settings(settings).node();
    node.start();
    client = node.client();

    if (newdb) {
        client.admin().indices().prepareDelete(indexKey).execute().actionGet();
        client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(indexKey).execute().actionGet();
    } else {
        boolean exists = client.admin().indices().exists(Requests.indicesExistsRequest(indexKey)).actionGet().isExists();
        if (!exists) {
            client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(indexKey).execute().actionGet();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Okay what I am finding is as follows

(any help from ElasticSearch-ers much appreciated!!!! 
     because I'm obviously doing something wrong     )

Even when the load shuts down leaving the data behind, the "run" still cannot find the data on startup

```
ElasticSearch node data path = C:\Users\Pl_2\AppData\Local\Temp\/esdata
org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: [es.ycsb][0] No shard available for [[es.ycsb][usertable][user4283669858964623926]: routing [null]]
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction.perform(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:140)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction.start(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:125)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction.doExecute(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:72)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportShardSingleOperationAction.doExecute(TransportShardSingleOperationAction.java:47)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:61)
at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.execute(NodeClient.java:83)
```

Answer (score 0):

The github README has been [updated](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/tree/master/elasticsearch).

It looks like you need to specify using:

```
-p path.home=<path to folder to persist data>
```